# spring mvc ajax data truncated with Jackson

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

0: {id: 1, name: "installation", description: "installing",…}

1: 2

2: 3

Above shown is an o/p of ajax. has any one faced or know why the data in 1 and 2 objects is missing. i tried to print the response list on server side. its ok there, all the value are printed. but when it comes to client side, data is missing

```
@RequestMapping(value="/events/month", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Event> getEventsForMonth()
{
    List<Event> events= eventService.getEventsForMonth();
    for(Event event:events)
        System.out.println(event.getName());

    return events;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any Jackson specific annotations on your model class like @JsonIdentityInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should produce JSON array of even objects: `[{"id":...}, {"id":...}]`.

First of all try to sniff the payload (e.g. via Zed Attach Proxy or Fiddler) to confirm that Spring + Jackson are not including more than one Event object.

If that is the case try to verify is there isn't any strange configuration of `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` in you Spring application. Try to remove it and observe behavior with default Jackson configuration.